# Apache loggin in to specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can I write something to .htaccess to make apache write log not to /var/log/apache2/*** (cause I don;t have permisiions to view them), but in other folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the log location

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog